# How CIunit supports HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpunit

I am using HMVC in my codeigniter project because use it help to group my modules together so that code is better organized.

When I integrate CIunit with codeigniter by following kenjis tutorials from [How to use PHPUnit (CIUnit) with CodeIgniter 2.1.0](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/Kenji_s/20120117/1326763908),  I got error when I try to run a test.

I get the following error:

```
[CIUnit] PHP Error: Notice - Trying to get property of non-object File Path: MX/Loader.php (line: 48)

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_module() on a non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\Project\application\third_party\MX\Loader.php on line 48
```

I read kenjis comments from [CIUnit + HMVC Issue](https://bitbucket.org/kenjis/my-ciunit/issue/7/ciunit-hmvc).

However, he says it's "ugly", not "impossible" to integrate them. Has anyone done this integration and gotten CIUnit and HMVC to work together?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, each module is a mini version of whole CodeIgniter framework. It seems possible to me that you

1. Set up a CIUnit testing environment with a fresh framework
2. Add one module's files to corresponding folders
3. Do testing
4. Repeat for each module

It would be tedious and time-consuming to set up testing environment for each module at first. But once you set them up, you will be able to test each module without modifying any core files.

Comment: I guess I was thinking from unit-testing point of view. This won't work for integration testing